# Tabulate results of PHP MYSQL search using class-search.php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search

So I have a large database (120k rows) and I'm building a little web app to make it useful for the community (astronomy based stuff). I'm new to php and am looking for a little help.
I have a search.php file and a class-search.php file and at the moment the results look like this:

```
2 results found

Array
(
    [count] => 2
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [disc] => LOC   7
                    [fstdate] => 2016
                    [lstdate] => 2016
                    [lstpa] => 170
                    [lstsep] => 0.4
                    [stype] => 
                    [comp] => AB
                    [fstmag] => 13.80
                    [secmag] => 14.10
                    [dnum] => 
                    [rahour] => 05
                    [ramin] => 38
                    [rasec] => 48.04
                    [decdeg] => -02
                    [decmin] => 27
                    [decsec] => 14.2
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [disc] => LOC   7
                    [fstdate] => 2016
                    [lstdate] => 2016
                    [lstpa] => 284
                    [lstsep] => 7.5
                    [stype] => 
                    [comp] => AB,C
                    [fstmag] => 13.20
                    [secmag] => 16.60
                    [dnum] => 
                    [rahour] => 05
                    [ramin] => 38
                    [rasec] => 48.04
                    [decdeg] => -02
                    [decmin] => 27
                    [decsec] => 14.2
                )

        )

)
```

I'm looking to tabulate the results and I have got a rough idea what I'm doing but I'm not quite getting everything joined up - can anyone suggest anything please.
The key part of search.php looks like this: (Code may not be fully accurate as I've taken out some switches and ifs to reduce post length)

```
<?php

//Check if search data was submitted
if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
  // Include the search class
  require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/class-search.php' );

  // Instantiate a new instance of the search class
  $search = new search();

  // Store search term into a variable
  $search_term = htmlspecialchars($_GET['s'], ENT_QUOTES);


  // Send the search term to our search class and store the result
  $search_results = $search->search($search_term);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WDSC search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Search the WDSC</h1>
    <div class="search-form">
      <form action="" method="get">
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="search-field">Search term</label>
          <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Enter your search term..." results="5" value="<?php echo $search_term; ?>">
          <input type="submit" value="Search">
          ........
      </form>
    </div>
    <?php if ( $search_results ) : ?>
  <div class="results-count">
      <p><?php echo $search_results['count']; ?> results found</p>
    </div>
    <div class="results-table">
      <?php foreach ( $search_results['results'] as $search_result ) : ?>
      <div class="result">        
        <p><?php echo $search_result->title; ?></p>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="search-raw">
      <pre><?php print_r($search_results); ?></pre>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the key parts of class-search.php looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Performs a search
 *
 * This class is used to perform search functions in a MySQL database
 *
 */
class search {
  /**
   * MySQLi connection
   * @access private
   * @var object
   */
  private $mysqli;

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * This sets up the class
   */
  public function __construct() {
    // Connect to our database and store in $mysqli property
    $this->connect();
  }
  /**
   * Database connection
   * 
   * This connects to our database
   */
  private function connect() {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli( 'server', 'user', 'pass', 'db' );
  }

  /**
   * Search routine
   * 
   * Performs a search
   * 
   * @param string $search_term The search term
   * 
   * @return array/boolen $search_results Array of search results or false
   */
  public function search($search_term) {
    // Sanitize the search term to prevent injection attacks
    $sanitized = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($search_term);
    // Define variable for search category from list selection
    $cat = $_GET['category'];


    // Run the query. 
    // Query for discoverer 
    $query = $this->mysqli->query("
      SELECT disc, fstdate, lstdate, lstpa, lstsep, stype, comp, fstmag, secmag, dnum, rahour, ramin, rasec, decdeg, decmin, decsec
      FROM WDS_CAT
      WHERE $cat LIKE '{$sanitized}%'

    ");
    }


    // Check results
    if ( ! $query->num_rows ) {
      return false;
    }

    // Loop and fetch objects
    while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
      $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // Build our return result
    $search_results = array(
      'count' => $query->num_rows,
      'results' => $rows,
    );

    return $search_results;
  }
}
endif;  
?>
```

I've tried to link a table to the variable $search_results by means of

```
echo '<table border=1px>';  // opening table tag
echo'<th>Discoverer</th><th>First year observed</th><th>Last year observed</th><th>Last position angle</th><th>Last separation</th><th>Spectral type</th><th>Components</th><th>Primary Magnitude</th><th>Secondary magnitude</th><th>Durchmusterung number</th><th>Right ascension</th><th></th><th></th><th>Declination</th><th></th><th></th>'; //table headers

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($search_results))
{
// we are running a while loop to print all the rows in a table
echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
echo '<td>'.$data['disc'].'</td><td>'.$data['fstdate'].'</td><td>'.$data['lstdate'].'</td><td>'.$data['lstpa'].'</td><td>'.$data['lstsep'].'</td><td>'.$data['stype'].'</td><td>'.$data['comp'].'</td><td>'.$data['fstmag'].'</td><td>'.$data['secmag'].'</td><td>'.$data['dnum'].'</td><td>'.$data['ragiyr'].'</td><td>'.$data['ramin'].'</td><td>'.$data['rasec'].'</td><td>'.$data['decdeg'].'</td><td>'.$data['decmin'].'</td><td>'.$data['decsec'].'</td>'; // we are looping all data to be printed till last row in the table
echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
}

echo '</table>';  //closing table tag
?>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

But no joy - can anyone suggest something please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didnt understand what is your problem... what do you mean by "tabulate results" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're just trying to output the results in a HTML table...?

UPDATE:

```
 foreach($search_results['results'] as $resultRow) {
      var_dump($resultRow);
   }
```

This should do the trick. You're returning the resultset already processed into your array so you just need to loop on that array and not call mysql_fetch_array() again

---

I would firstly add

```
var_dump($data);
exit();
```

right after

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($search_results))
{
```

to loop only once and see what each loop returns. It's probably only returning [count] and [results] arrays so you might need to loop again on [results] array. Review the PHP reference for mysql_fetch_array http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

e.g.

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($search_results))
{
if(is_array($data['results'])){
   foreach($data['results'] as $resultRow) {
      var_dump($resultRow);
   }
}
```

Within the foreach loop you can add your HTML output as you have above

NOTE: All this is based on the assumption that mysql_fetch_array() returns the the data structure as per your first code snippet.

```
2 results found

Array
(
    [count] => 2
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
```

Comment: I'll try your suggestion tomorrow - I am indeed trying to output my results to an HTML table. Thanks

Comment: Please note you will need some form of pagination as 120K records displayed will either run out of PHP memory or crash your browser... always limit your resultsets! :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!!

I eventually turned on my brain and worked out that the return from the dump was an object not an array, so I cast it to an array using `$resultsArray = (array)$resultRow;` and ran that into the table.

It's dirty, but this is now doing what I want. Thanks @JI-Web, I couldn't have done it without your help. I think I'm getting the hang of PHP now.
Onto pagination and pulling relevant data from 3rd party sources into a frame based on the results. I may be back for more help!